# Property additionalActions of NSUserNotification seems not working?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsusernotification

To understand NSUserNotification better, I wrote a little test app playing with this class.

So far so good, except that no matter how hard I tried to feed the additionalActions property with array of NSUserNotificationAction objects, it never showed any difference but only one action button and a close one.

My expectation for this property is that the notification would show a pull-down menu containing the additional buttons I offer as it does in the Mac App Store update notifications.

Am I missing something? Or are you having the same problem, since it is a bug awaiting Apple to tackle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try to click and hold down the action button in your notification? Does it show a drop-down menu of `additionalActions`?

---

### Update

As it turns out, you can show the little chevron next to the action button by setting a true value for the private `_alwaysShowAlternateActionMenu` key on the notification. In Swift 3, it would look like this:

```
notification.setValue(true, forKey: "_alwaysShowAlternateActionMenu")
```

However, as I mentioned this is a private API and I strongly advise against using it if you want to distribute your App through the Mac App Store.

Comment: As it turns out, the the pull-down button behavior of App Store or Reminder needs a private property named _alternateActionButtonTitles_ . Sorry for the belated response.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bug. Setting up `additionalActions` will create the list, but not the little arrow icon. Holding down on `actionButton` will show the menu with the number of actions you set.

Besides setting `additionalActions` will cause several other problems. I will save this for another question.

Refer to another question.
[show NSUserNotification additionalActions on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631218/show-nsusernotification-additionalactions-on-click)

P.S. I am using El Capitan APIs